# Primary account in Adaptive Payments in PayPal

Tags: paypal

I have used Adaptive Payments method of PayPal.
Its working fine. But we have one small changes.

Currently in our site there are two receiver of order(payment).
Suppose there $100 of order then $10 will be transfer in to site owner and $90 will be transfer in to shop owner(Other user).

Currently we have set our site owner account as primary account(Primary account is a business account where we have set up chained payment featured). and Shop owner(other user and it is simple Paypal account) as secondary account.

I want to change to shop owner account as a primary account intend of site owner.

Can i set any of PayPal account as a Primary account?